# vagrant INIT works, vagrant UP - doesn't work

Tags: windows, vagrant, git-bash

I have installed `Git, VirtualBox and Vargant on my Windows 10` computer.
Have problems with starting Vargant using git-bash console.

When I do **`vargant init`** - this create vargant file and looks like it's ok.

```
Alex@DESKTOP MINGW64 /d/shell
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
```

But when I try to start vagrant with **`vagrant up`** command I receive error.

```
Alex@DESKTOP MINGW64 /d/shell
$ vagrant up
bash: vagrant: command not found
```

I have tried restarting, reinstalling these software, installing latest or previouse versions of software - nothing helps - still `bash: vagrant: command not found`.

What shell I do next to solve the problem?

Comment: assuming `vargant` in your example is a typo? and you are actually typing `vagrant` in the shell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the command / program name is `vagrant`  , not `vargant`.  You spell it correctly in the init, but the rest of your examples have it spelled incorrect. Try running `vagrant up` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you, first example was copied and second was printed myself. I couple of days haven't seen this misspelling in my attempts!

Comment: it happens.  Also if you look at some of that research in cognitive / brain science, they have shown if all the letters are there, but in wrong order, brain interprets it as whole word and puts it in order. Which is pretty interesting as well.